# Easily merge multiple CSS classes to a single CSS file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap HTML/CSS template with more than 40+ different CSS files. I sometimes only use 1 class from a CSS file and therefore there is a lot of excess CSS. Is there a program or solutions that allows me to quickly gather all the active classes from the 40+ CSS files and merge them in one single CSS file?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Yeah 41 times ctrl+c and ctrl+v does the trick.Belive me Try it ;)

Comment: I am interested in the answer though :)

Comment: @FlyingGambit This did the trick for me: https://www.unused-css.com/. Search for remove unused css and you will find a lot of tools.

Comment: @user1797935 Thanks for the link, it will come handy

Answer (score 0):

Try SASS with imports.
http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

You can use normal CSS in SCSS files, so you wouldn't need to change anything.

And if you are using Bootstrap, there is a Bootstrap version based on SASS so you can modify it without much CSS:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download